# How do I update the content of body instead of adding to existing content?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm creating a simple practice weather page where you get weather data for a particular city.

Currently when I enter a city it displays the data by creating ul/li elements, but when I enter a second city instead of replacing and updating the existing elements, it just adds the data for the second city under the first city.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let cityName = document.querySelector("#city");
  let button = document.querySelector("#submit");
  // Checks value type and displays property and value.
  let logLi = function(k, j) {
    if (typeof j === 'object') {
      isObject(j);
    } else {
      let li = document.createElement('LI');
      let liText = document.createTextNode('\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0' + k + ": " + j);
      li.appendChild(liText)
      document.querySelector('body').appendChild(li);
    }
  }
  // Checks Object's name type, and displays name of object or Array
  let logUl = function(x) {
    if (isNaN(x)) {
      let output = document.createElement('UL');
      let outputText = document.createTextNode(x);
      output.appendChild(outputText);
      document.querySelector('body').appendChild(output);
    }
  }

  // Calls logLi on every value in object
  let isObject = function(x) {
    for (let i in x) {
      logLi(i, x[i]);
    }
  };

  //Updates Query url when user submits their city
  let city = function() {
    let api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
    let units = "&units=metric&APPID=xxxxxxx"
    let url;
    url = api + cityName.value + units;

    //Breaks down the JSON
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        let sort = function(x) {
          for (let k in x) {
            if (typeof x[k] == 'number' || typeof x[k] == 'string') {
              logLi(k, x[k]);
            } else if (Array.isArray(x[k])) {
              logUl(k);
              sort(x[k]);
            } else if (typeof x[k] == 'object') {
              logUl(k);
              isObject(x[k]);
            }
          }
        }
        sort(data);

      });
    });
  }
  //Submition
  button.onclick = city;
  cityName.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      city();
    }
  });

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="city" value="London"></input>
  <button type="button" return false id="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The posted code, is not simplified enough. Please simplify/minimize the code to make it runnable within Stackoverflow and still produce the same issue.

Comment: Well, you are .appending each item received, not doing any kind of checking for already existing cities and replacing them if so.  Perhaps you can add an attribute to the LI, eg `data-city` containing the city name, then look to see if you already have `document.querySelector(‘li[data-city=some-city]’)` and replace the content if you do, otherwise append a new li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit hard to read but i "cracked it".
I made it work like this:

1) I've added a new div with an ID of "weather"

```
<form>
<input id="city" value="London"></input>
<button type="button" return false id="submit">submit</button>
</form>
<div id="weather"></div>
```

2) After this in js script add a new variable

`let weather = document.getElementById('weather');` at begining inside `window.onload` function

3) In code change occurances of `document.querySelector('body')` with `weather`

4) In the end inside `city` function at begining add `weather.innerHTML = '';` This will clear the html of weather like there is nothing in it.

Here is the example, just run the code snippet:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let cityName = document.querySelector("#city");
  let button = document.querySelector("#submit");
  let weather = document.getElementById('weather');
  // Checks value type and displays property and value.
  let logLi = function(k, j) {
    if (typeof j === 'object') {
      isObject(j);
    } else {
      let li = document.createElement('LI');
      let liText = document.createTextNode('\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0' + k + ": " + j);
      li.appendChild(liText)
      weather.appendChild(li);
    }
  }
  // Checks Object's name type, and displays name of object or Array
  let logUl = function(x) {
    if (isNaN(x)) {
      let output = document.createElement('UL');
      let outputText = document.createTextNode(x);
      output.appendChild(outputText);
      weather.appendChild(output);
    }
  }

  // Calls logLi on every value in object
  let isObject = function(x) {
    for (let i in x) {
      logLi(i, x[i]);
    }
  };

  //Updates Query url when user submits their city
  let city = function() {
    weather.innerHTML = '';
    let api = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
    let units = "&units=metric&APPID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    let url;
    url = api + cityName.value + units;

    //Breaks down the JSON
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        let sort = function(x) {
          for (let k in x) {
            if (typeof x[k] == 'number' || typeof x[k] == 'string') {
              logLi(k, x[k]);
            } else if (Array.isArray(x[k])) {
              logUl(k);
              sort(x[k]);
            } else if (typeof x[k] == 'object') {
              logUl(k);
              isObject(x[k]);
            }
          }
        }
        sort(data);

      });
    });
  }
  //Submition
  button.onclick = city;
  cityName.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      city();
    }
  });

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="city" value="London"></input>
  <button type="button" return false id="submit">submit</button>
</form>
<div id="weather"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the exact behavior I was looking for. 
This is the first time I wrote code for others to see. If you have the time, can you please elaborate on what made my code hard to read at first?